# Windows Phone 8: Parse Push Notifications Invalid Response from Server Error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, parse-platform

I had followed the short tutorial given in the quickstart page of Parse.com, Push Notifications works fine in my app, but the problem is when there is no network connection in the phone, the app crashes with exception.

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Parse.ParseException: Invalid response from server ---> System.ArgumentException: Input JSON was invalid.at Parse.Internal.Json.Parse(String input)

I had tried checking the network by using DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable before initializing the ParseClient, but it works only when there is no network connection at all.
I want it to work when Server is not responding.

```
            ParseClient.Initialize("My App Id", "My .Net id");
            this.Startup += async (sender, args) =>
            {
                ParseAnalytics.TrackAppOpens(RootFrame);

                await ParsePush.SubscribeAsync("");
            };
            ParsePush.ToastNotificationReceived +=ParsePushOnToastNotificationReceived;
```

I'm calling the above code inside App().

Comment: Can you please post the line of code giving you problems?

Comment: Nahuel Ianni, Updated it.

Comment: Solution? Having the same problem here